# Return statement gets executed earlier than the piece of code in protractor

Tags: typescript, protractor

Return statement gets executed earlier than the piece of code in protractor

```
public newcc(newc:string):boolean
{
  var Outcome:boolean=false;

  this.Cc.getText().then(function (text){
    var Name=text.toString();
    var str_array = Name.split(',');

    console.log("Cce : "+Name);

    for(var i:number=0;i<str_array.length;i++) {
      // if the name is found then make the outcome true and break 
      if(str_array[i]==cc) {
        console.log(str_array[i] +" is equal to "+ClinicName);
        Outcome=true;
        console.log("Inside Outcome " +Outcome);
        break;
      } else {
        console.log(str_array[i] +" is not equal to "+Cc); 
      }
    }        
  });  

  return Outcome;
  // the return always exectued earlier than above `this.ClinicList.getText()`
}
```

Because of this always the method returns false even if it is true.

Comment: It's not clear what your question is.  The code is meant to be executed after the return.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually `return` is executed behind of `this.ClinicList.getText()`.  To get a clear understanding, you need to know all protractor API are executed Async and return promise, you also need to understand promise.

When Nodejs execute this function, when run to line `this.ClinicList.getText().then()`, this line return a pomise, then move to run the next line: `return Outcome`.

The key point is the `getText()` is Async, so the actual work to read text from page is executed asynce, so the actual work is start later than nodejs executing `return Outcome`.

```
public CliniclistClinicAvailability(ClinicName:string): any
{

  // i guess this.ClinicList is decleared as `element.all()`

  return this.ClinicList.getText().then(function (texts){
     // texts is an Array<string>
     return texts.includes(ClinicName);
  )};
}

// how to use above function:
// CliniclistClinicAvailability return a promise, 
// you need to consumer the promise's eventually value in `then()`
CliniclistClinicAvailability('Test').then(function(isAvailable:boolean){
   console.log('isAvailable: ' + isAvailable);
});
```